# If $\sin C=\frac{\sin A}{2\cos B}$, then prove that the triangle is isosceles

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sin A=2\sin C \cos B$$
$$\sin A=\sin (C+B)+\cos (C-B)$$
$$cos(C-B)=0$$
$$C-B=90$$
This doesn’t prove that the triangle is isosceles. What’s wrong here?

Comment: *check your second line

Comment: Another way: $$2c(c^2+a^2-b^2)=2ca^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line should be $$ \sin A=\sin (C+B)+\color{red}{\sin} (C-B).$$
Then the conclusion will end up at $B=C$.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in
$$\sin A = \sin(C+B) + \cos(C-B)$$
It should be
$$\sin A = \sin(C+B) + \sin(C-B)$$
Then, for $\sin(C-B)=0$, you have $B=C$, which proves that the triangle is isosceles.

Comment: Yeah terrible mistake on my part